# Predicting possible inputs leading to output satisfying certain condition

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose there is a data set of statistical data with a number of input columns and one output column. The predictors characterize some particular process that is repeated, so one data row is corresponding to one occasion of that process. And for these process characteristics the order and duration is important. Some of them might be absent at all, some of them are repeated, but with different speed or other parameter.

Let's say that our process is names P and it can have a lot of child parts, that form the process together. Let's say, once the process had N sub processes:

1. Sub process 1, with: speed = SpdA, duration = DurA, depth = DepA

Right after sub process A next sub process B happened:

2. Sub process 2, with: speed = SpdB, duration = DurB, depth = DepB

...

... N. Sub process N.

So there might be from 1 to N child processes in each process, that is, in each data row. And the amount of the child processes may vary from one row to another. This is about the input data.

As for the output - the output here in the simplest case is binary - either success or failure, but in reality it will be a positive number starting from 0 to positive infinity. This number represents the time by which the process has finished successfully. If the value for the output is a positive infinity - it means that the process failed to succeed.

Very important note, if we are going with the simplest case where the output is binary - in the statistical data set there will be data rows that mostly have failure in the output. The goal is to find the hypothetical parameters that values of the test predictors should be equal to, to make the process succeed.

For example, after learning we should be able to tell what is the concrete universal input parameters that will most process success. That was the simplest, binary output case.

However, in real life we will have the output that represents time by which the process finished successfully, and +infinity - if failure. So here the goal is the same - make the process succeed or as much close to success as possible. The goal is to generate the test inputs that we might use in future to prevent the output equal to +infinity.

The goal maximum is, having the target time provided, find the exact values for the inputs that will make the process finish successfully as closer to the given time as possible. Here we should expect the enumeration of child processes, their order and the values for each child process to be predicted.

Here in this problem, I guess, the output will play the role of the input and the input will play the role of the output.

What is the approach to solve these problems? How to handle the variable number of characteristics and how to handle the order that might vary in the each data row?

I am a novice in machine learning and would appreciate the concrete suggestions or examples of similar problems solved.

Any help and advice welcome!

Comment: I believe a [neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) implementation may work for you, but this question is probably too broad to get a good answer.

Comment: @dave it is not broad, it's very narrow. I have tried to explain it almost literally.. What kind of neural network? What topology? How to handle the variable number of characteristics and how to handle the order that might vary in the each data row?

Comment: The wall of text is hard to comprehend. Standard NN's require fixed size inputs. You could create multiple networks with different lengths of inputs, and aggregate over them in some way. If the processes are pieces of software you could also try to squeeze your problem into a genetic algorithm of some sort. This problem sounds hard and probably isn't going to be easy.